# Missing bits - Text-to-Binary JS

Tags: javascript, tostring

I am working on a code written from someone else. While examining the code I noticed that during the conversion there is `0` bit that gets removed. Here is an example of the code:

```
user_input = 'a'
        
input_bits = '';
for (let i = 0; i < user_input.length; i++) {
    input_bits += user_input.charCodeAt(i).toString(2);
}
```

When I run this code the value in `input_bits` is: `1100001`. I used an online converter and the result is: `01100001`. I think in my case missing bits is important because if i want to convert another string for example `ab` my version of the code will give `11000011100010` and the expected value should be `0110000101100010`.

How can I fix that. I tried an `if` statement in the loop to append the missing `0` bits until the length is 8, but that lead to even stranger results.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) with zeros to length 8:

```js
user_input = 'a'
    
input_bits = '';
for (let i = 0; i < user_input.length; i++) {
    input_bits += user_input.charCodeAt(i).toString(2).padStart(8, "0");
}
console.log(input_bits)
```